# How to bar plot grouped by two variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I have 15-minute timestep data of a quantity for serveral years...

| Datetime | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 01/07/2018 00:15 | 6.96 |
| 01/07/2018 00:30 | 6.48 |
| 01/07/2018 00:45 | 6.96 |
| 01/07/2018 01:00 | 6.72 |
| . | . |
| . | . |

I am using Pandas. How do I produce a bar plot with months on the horizontal axis; and a series (set of bars) for each year; with the height of each bar being the total quantity for that month & year.

Exactly like this:

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fake dataframe creation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Datetime'] = pd.date_range(start = '01/07/2018', end = '13/08/2021', freq = '15min')
df['Quantity'] = np.random.rand(len(df))
```

Starting from this point, you should extract month and year and save them in separate columns:

```
df['month'] = df['Datetime'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['Datetime'].dt.year
```

Then you have to compute the sum of `'Quantity'` by month for each year:

```
df = df.groupby(by = ['month', 'year'])['Quantity'].sum().reset_index()
```

After this passage, you should have a dataframe like this:

```
             Datetime  Quantity  month  year
0 2018-01-07 00:00:00  0.226113      1  2018
1 2018-01-07 00:15:00  0.222872      1  2018
2 2018-01-07 00:30:00  0.835484      1  2018
3 2018-01-07 00:45:00  0.775771      1  2018
4 2018-01-07 01:00:00  0.972559      1  2018
5 2018-01-07 01:15:00  0.418036      1  2018
6 2018-01-07 01:30:00  0.902843      1  2018
7 2018-01-07 01:45:00  0.012441      1  2018
8 2018-01-07 02:00:00  0.883437      1  2018
9 2018-01-07 02:15:00  0.183561      1  2018
```

Now the dataframe is ready to be plotted; using seaborn:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.barplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'month', y = 'Quantity', hue = 'year')

plt.show()
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Datetime'] = pd.date_range(start = '01/07/2018', end = '13/08/2021', freq = '15min')
df['Quantity'] = np.random.rand(len(df))
df['month'] = df['Datetime'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['Datetime'].dt.year

df = df.groupby(by = ['month', 'year'])['Quantity'].sum().reset_index()


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.barplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'month', y = 'Quantity', hue = 'year')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can extract months and years into new columns and make multiple subplots with months in the x axis, one for each year, and combine them all at the end in a unique plot. Take a look at the example below, and notice the width parameter and the displacement by the same value in `plt.bar`, so that plots don't cover each other.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

# create df
d1 = datetime.date(2018, 8, 30)
d2 = datetime.date(2018, 9, 30)
d3 = datetime.date(2019, 8, 30)
d4 = datetime.date(2019, 9, 30)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [d1, d1, d2, d2, d3, d3, d4, d4],
    'values':[10, 20, 40, 40, 50, 55, 65, 70]})

df['month'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.month)
df['year'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.year)

# make plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.bar(df[df.year == 2018].groupby(['month']).sum()['values'].index, df[df.year == 2018].groupby(['month']).sum()['values'])
ax = plt.bar(df[df.year == 2019].groupby(['month']).sum()['values'].index, df[df.year == 2019].groupby(['month']).sum()['values'])
plt.show()
```

Maybe creating new columns as I did won't be very efficient for you if you have a very large dataframe. To make the plots, I filtered rows by year in each line, grouped them by month and used the sum of values. The indexes are tuples `(year, month)`.